# Schwarz inequality for unital completely positive maps

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

I came across the following form of Schwarz inequality for completely positive maps in [Arveson's paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-44/issue-2/Notes-on-extensions-of-C-algebras/10.1215/S0012-7094-77-04414-3.short):

> Let $\delta:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ be a unital completely positive linear map between two $C^*$-algebras, then \begin{equation}\delta(A)^*\delta(A)\le \delta(A^*A),\end{equation}

which is a crucial part in proving proposition 3.

I do not know this inequality and thus searched on wiki, something related is

> (Kadison-Schwarz) If $\phi$ is a unital positive map, then \begin{equation}\phi(a^*a)\ge\phi(a^*)\phi(a)\end{equation} for all normal elements $a$.

However, I cannot find a proof of Kadison-Schwarz. Also, since Kadison-Schwarz works only for normal elements, there seems to be a gap between Kadison-Schwarz and Schwarz.

I wonder where I can find a proof to the first inequality.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that Kadison-Schwarz is stated for positive (not necessarily cp) maps; that's why the restriction to normals is required (the C$^*$-algebra generated by a normal is abelian, and then any positive map is completely positive).

Also, for Schwarz inequality all that is required is 2-positivity (which of course is implied by complete positivity).

This is the proof of the inequality as in Paulsen's book:

We have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&a \\ a^*& a^*a\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&a\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}^*\begin{bmatrix}1&a\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}\geq0.
$$
Then
$$
0\leq\delta^{(2)}\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&a \\ a^*& a^*a\end{bmatrix}\right)
=\begin{bmatrix}1&\delta(a) \\ \delta(a)^*& \delta(a^*a)\end{bmatrix}
$$
Applying this in particular to the vector $\begin{bmatrix}-\delta(a)\eta\\ \eta\end{bmatrix}$, we get
$$
0\leq\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}1&\delta(a) \\ \delta(a)^*& \delta(a^*a)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-\delta(a)\eta\\ \eta\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-\delta(a)\eta\\ \eta\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle=\langle(\delta(a^*a)-\delta(a)^*\delta(a))\eta,\eta\rangle.
$$
As the vector $\eta$ can be chosen arbitrarily, we conclude that $\delta(a^*a)-\delta(a)^*\delta(a)\geq0$.

Comment: Thanks! Quite elegant proof. But I guess in the second inequality it should be \le.

Comment: It's corrected now. Thanks!